# how to proof this formally, that sin(1/x) has no limit

Tags: limits

We want to show that $sin(1/x)$ does not have a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$. I prove by contradiction that we cannot make the following be true $$|sin(1/x) - L| < \epsilon$$ 
regardless of $\delta$, i.e. no matter how close to $0$ x is.

We know that sin($\pi/2 +$ $2\pi n$) $= 1. $ Let us rewrite $\pi/2 + 2\pi n$ to a fraction. We'd get $\frac{\pi(4n+1)}{2}$. Were we to evaluate our function in this $x$ value, we'd get the reciprocal, so if we were to evaluate it in the reciprocal, $\frac{2}{\pi(4n+1)}$, we'd get that the function equals 1.

Now, letting $n$ approach infinity, we see that this expression approaches 0, and thus all we can always pick an $n$ so that in some infinitely small interval around $0$, $sin(1/x)$ takes on the value $1$.

Something similar can be done for $-1$.

Now, I don't know what to do in the final step. Obviously sin(1/x) takes on two different values periodically as x gets close to zero (we just pick $n$ to be large enough), but I knew that already. Is this enough for the proof, or?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's enough to prove that. To complete your argument use facts(let $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$):

1. Suppose that $f(x)$ has limit.
2. If $f(x)$ has limit, then series $f(\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2})$ is convergent.
3. Every convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
4. But you've proven that it is not Cauchy sequence.